# How to pass a Class object with generics of a base interface?

Tags: java, generics

So I have the following method:

```
void doSomething(Class<MyInterface> klass) { }
```

Great! Now I do:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface { }

// now let's call the method
doSomething(MyClass.class); // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Why ??? How do I solve this without adding generics to the class that has the method doSomething?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why ???

Because generics are not covariant. Even though `MyInterface` is super type of `MyClass`, `Class<MyInterface>` is not super type of `Class<MyClass>`.

> How do I solve this without adding generics to the class that has the method doSomething?

Change your method definition to:

```
void doSomething(Class<? extends MyInterface> klass) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
<K extends MyInterface> void doSomething(Class<K> klass) { }
```

Then you can use the generic K inside the method, if needed.